# C++ template specialization: change return type of operator()?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, template-specialization, return-type

In the following class I have defined an `operator()` returning a vector of `return_T`:

```
#include <vector>

template <typename return_T, typename ... arg_T>
class A
{
public:
    std::vector<return_T> operator()(arg_T... args);
};
```

This works, except in the case where `return_T = void`, since a `vector<void>` is impossible. So I'll need to define a specialization of `A<void, arg_T>::operator()` somehow. I'm experimenting with the following code:

```
#include <vector>

template <typename return_T, typename ... arg_T>
class A
{
public:
    auto operator()(arg_T... args);
};

template<typename return_T, typename... arg_T>
auto A<return_T, arg_T...>::operator()(arg_T... args) -> typename std::enable_if<!std::is_void<return_T>::value, std::vector<return_T>>::type
{ }

template<typename return_T, typename... arg_T>
auto A<void, arg_T...>::operator()(arg_T... args) -> void
{ }
```

But the compiler doesn't like it.

```
error : prototype for 'typename std::enable_if<(! std::is_void<_Tp>::value), std::vector<_Tp> >::type A<return_T, arg_T>::operator()(arg_T ...)' does not match any in class 'A<return_T, arg_T>'
   auto A<return_T, arg_T...>::operator()(arg_T... args) -> typename std::enable_if<!std::is_void<return_T>::value, std::vector<return_T>>::type

error : candidate is: auto A<return_T, arg_T>::operator()(arg_T ...)
       auto operator()(arg_T... args);
            ^

error : invalid use of incomplete type 'class A<void, arg_T ...>'
   auto A<void, arg_T...>::operator()(arg_T... args) -> void
                                                        ^
```

Of course, I could easily write a second class with `void operator()`, but I'm curious if it could be done with a single class too. So there's my question: is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

template <typename return_T, typename... arg_T>
class A
{
public:
    auto operator()(arg_T... args)
    {
        return invoke(std::is_void<return_T>{}, std::forward<arg_T>(args)...);
    }

private:
    void invoke(std::true_type, arg_T&&... args)
    {
    }

    std::vector<return_T> invoke(std::false_type, arg_T&&... args)
    {
        return {};
    }
};
```

Test:

```
int main()
{
    A<int, char, short> a;    
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(a('x', 5)), std::vector<int>>{}, "!");

    A<void, char, short> b;
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(b('x', 5)), void>{}, "!");    
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7d3b7693182739d2)

Answer (score 5):

Instead of specializing `A`, you could create a "traits" class that you specialize:

```
template <typename return_T>
struct Traits {
    using ReturnType = std::vector<return_T>;
};

template <>
struct Traits<void> {
    using ReturnType = void;
}

template <typename return_T, typename ... arg_T>
class A
{
public:

    typename Traits<return_T>::ReturnType operator()(arg_T... args);
};
```

This way you don't have to specialize `A`, which can be convenient if `A` is large and specializing it would be more complex than just specializing a small traits class.

Comment: I came up with the same solution (but you are faster +1). However I noticed that it is very hard to get the body `operator()` right with useful implementation.

Comment: @BryanChen: Indeed, the actual body of the function can be more complicated. But since the OP didn't have anything in their body I left it as simple as possible.

Comment: If the only special case is `void`, then `std::conditional` works just fine without the need to introduce a separate traits class.

Comment: I'm trying this but still can't specialize the actual function... and using a single function with `if (typeid(T) == typeid(void))` won't compile either. :(

Comment: @Cornstalks this answer makes little sense, how do you imagine writing the body of this function?